# UIScrollViewでpagingした時に、最後のページの右端に変な余白が残ってしまいます。

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview

画像１のように右端に隙間（黒い部分）ができます。
画像２の位置に戻って欲しいのですが。

全体の作りは、

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        w = view.frame.size.width

        _images = Utils.loadImages(album: album)

        _contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        let totalW = w * CGFloat(_images.count)
        _contentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: totalW, height: 0)
        _scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size

for i in 0..<_images.count {
        let img = _images[i]
        let v = addImageView(index: i)
        v.image = img
    }
   }
func addImageView(index: Int) -> UIImageView{
    let rect = CGRect(x: w*CGFloat(index), y: 0, width: w, height: h)
    let v = UIImageView(frame: rect)
    v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    v.clipsToBounds = true
    _contentView.addSubview(v)
    return v
}
```

とし、各ページに画像が表示されるようにしています。

storybordでのscrollViewの設定は画像3のようにしています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
画像１

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
画像２

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
画像３

Comment: _scrollViewに画像をaddsubviewしている個所を教えてください。余談ですが、この手のページングはUICollectionViewを利用された方がよいです。UIScrollViewだとすべての画像をメモリにロードしますので、メモリ負荷が非常に高くなります。

Comment: 3枚以上の画像を表示すると最後のページだけずれますか？それとも徐々にずれ幅が大きくなりますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまくいく時もあります。たしかにページ数が少ないときはうまくいくかもしれません。重いせいかもしれません。

Comment: addImageViewの返り値のvのx座標をデバッグ出力してみてください。すべてwの倍数になっていますか？

Comment: print(rect.origin.x)で0.0
414.0
828.0
1242.0
1656.0です。余白なしです。12枚にしても症状がでなくなりました。大丈夫かもしれません。

Comment: 少し気持ち悪いですが、問題解決ということでしょうか？どういった部分を修正したかを自己解決という形で回答いただけると、助かります。

Comment: 実際は特に何もしないで、自然と治った感じです。一応その旨書いておきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像ページが多すぎると重くなり、この症状が出るようです。

アドバイスいただいたようにコレクションビューでやった方が良いかもしれません。